# Правильно ли я посчитал асимптотическую сложность алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

```
void MaxValueInArray()
{
    Random rand = new Random(); // O(1)
    int[] array = new int[rand.Next(0, 10)]; // O(1)
    int lagerst = 0; //O(1)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) // заполнение массива  0(N)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(0, 100);
        Console.Write($"{array[i]} ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) //O(N)
    {
        if (array[i] > lagerst)
        {
            lagerst = array[i];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"\nНаибольшее число: {lagerst}"); //O(1)
    //Сложность алгоритма O(1+1+N+N+1) = O(3+2N)
}
```

Comment: Сложность O(n).

Comment: Забавно, что если вы уж пытаетесь учитывать "3+2N", то почему упускаете операцию сравнения и операцию присваивания? :)

Answer (score 5):

Неверно, т.к. *вкратце без подробностей* в нотации `O` не учитываются константы.
Т.е. `O(2n) == O(n)`, `O(3) == O(1)`, `O(3+2N) == O(N)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

По-другому ещё можно сказать, что финальный подсчёт должен вестись взятием максимальной сложности среди частей алгоритма:

```
max(O(1), O(1), O(N), O(N), O(1)) -> O(N)
```